# unittest installation error Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: python, python-unittest

Could someone please help me with this error message:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement unittest
```

I installed the latest `Python` and `PyCharm` and try to install the package `unittest` but get the above error. So far my experience with `Python` is a bit like dll hell ...

Comment: python + windows is like hell...   If you can change to linux or mac, everything run smooth. ;)

Comment: sorry but I thought Python is truly platform agnostic haha

Comment: I used Pycharm but also tried pip install unittest via command line

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you tried this:

```
$ pip install unittest
Collecting unittest

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement unittest (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for unittest
```

It's normal to have an error because [`unittest`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest/0.0) is not a valid package on Pypi. The only distributable is `unittest2-0.0.0.tar.gz` but the name is not correct, it should be `unittest-0.0.0.tar.gz` (without "2"). In fact I think it's an error and if you want to use this one you need to install [`unittest2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2) (which is a backport of `unittest` for Python 2.6).

But **[`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) is a standard module, which you don't need to install**:

```
$ python -m unittest

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```