# Running Travis-CI off of github

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, travis-ci

I have a Windows machine so I' trying to have Travis CI run my python scripts directly from github. Is it possible to run Travis CI python scripts directly from my github and not from my local repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate [TracisCI to your GItHub repo](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/getting-started/)

That way, on each push, your associated TravisCI job will run and execute what you have specified.

Regarding your `travis.yaml`, it has to respect the [yaml syntax format](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/YAMLSyntax.html):

```
language: python 
sudo: enabled
python:
  -"3.5"  <========= incorrect: must be - "3.5"
```

See [Building a Python Project](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/): you will see a space between `-` and `"x.y"` version.

Regarding the `unittest` error, see "[unittest installation error Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46133353/6309)"

> [**`unittest`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) is a standard module, which you don't need to install.

Comment: I'm having a few difficulties. I wasn't specific before and I'm sorry for that.

Comment: I'm still having trouble after fixing the issue with the space                                          
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement unittest (from   
    versions: )
    No matching distribution found for unittest
    The command "pip install unittest" failed and exited with 1 during

Comment: @MatthewAnderson That is an entirely different question: I have resolved your initial question